# What is the difference between ArcGIS Pro, ArcGIS Desktop and ArcGIS for Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro

I have purchased GIS for personal use. I am very new to GIS. I am confused with the products. Which one should I use?

[image]

Comment: ArcGIS *for* Desktop 10.4.1 is the same 32-bit product as ArcGIS Desktop 10.6, just an earlier release. Pro is a different beast entirely, built to be 64-bit from the ground up. Which one to use is more of a religious question than something which could be answered in our "Focused question / Best answer" model.

Comment: Which one have you done training with or have experience in? ArcGIS (for) Desktop has been fairly much the same since the early days with only a few quirks changing, so if you've done training or have experience in a previous version it should be easy(er) to get started in that product. Conversely if you have no experience or training in either toss a coin, go with the cheaper option or look at the online courses and decide which has better training.

Comment: If you are new to GIS, then I would recommend starting with ArcGIS Pro, unless you are working on a project or in an organisation that requires you to use the older ArcGIS Desktop architecture.  At the moment I suspect that there are many more users of ArcGIS Desktop than ArcGIS Pro, but I expect that the process of that flipping is well underway.

Comment: Don't forget to take the [Tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Comment: If you have purchased a product as you say, which one did you purchase? The licensing is different for both products, best to stick with what you paid for.

Comment: @MichaelStimson They are all included in the licence

Comment: @MichaelStimson [ArcGIS for Personal Use](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgis-for-personal-use) includes Pro, Desktop and some Online credits.

Comment: There are certain advanced capabilities  in Desktop which aren't yet available in Pro, and some new features which are only available in Pro. For full functionality of the ArcGIS platform, you need both.

Comment: @PolyGeo, does that mean you can install Pro and Desktop on a personal license to evaluate both? Wont they have issues with python installs? Pro-654bit, Desktop-32bit...

Comment: @MichaelStimson Pro installs and uses Python 3 64bit while Desktop installs and uses Python 2.7 32bit. I only do vanilla installs and have had no problems running both on same laptop for about 3 years.